# Add the last entry object into an arraylist using for-each loop java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the last element of an Entry object and add into an arraylist of Entry objects(so it will only store one Entry object in the arraylist).The reason I am doing this is that I need that ArrayList to be used in another class.

Source code:

```
ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>> allEntries = new ArrayList<Entry<String,Integer>>();
Iterator <Entry <String,Integer>> entries = post.getCategory().entrySet().iterator();
 while(entries.hasNext()) {
  Entry <String,Integer> entry = entries.next();
if(topic.getField("categoryName").equals(entry.getKey())){                                                            
  int increaseCount = entry.getValue();
  increaseCount++;
  entry.setValue(increaseCount);
}
for(Entry<String,Integer> entrySet : post.getCategory().entrySet()){
  if(!entries.hasNext()){
     allEntries.add(entrySet);                      
  }
}
```

Comment: I want only the last Entry object in the arraylist,but this code will add all Entry objects into the arraylist.

Comment: Problem with the set is that it doesn't maintain the order.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't maintain the order"?

Comment: That means conceptually there is no such thing as position of elements. So the last element you get from the set could be any one no matter in which order you added them.

Comment: It is because for the part where I get the categories in the for-each loop,those data are being stored in a Java properties file.So I do not think it is possible to get position of an element.